# Remove specified tags in XML (notepad++)

Tags: xml, tags, notepad++

I have a (very) big XML file for my gps track.  It's built like this:

```
<trkpt lat="45.4818095" lon="3.76271898">
        <time>2010-08-29T17:20:52Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="45.48068593" lon="3.762722181">
        <time>2010-08-29T17:21:37Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="45.47923258" lon="3.762515148">
        <time>2010-08-29T17:22:35Z</time>
    </trkpt>
```

I want to share my GPS track, but all the information between the `<time>` and `</time>` is useless.  Is there a way to delete these tags in notepad++?

Comment: Search for `<time>.*</time>(\r\n)` and replace with blank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always do a find and replace:

find `<time>[0-9A-Z:-]*</time>` and replace with blank (make sure Regular Expressions is checked)

---

**EDIT:**

Quick clarification, this replaces everything in the text file that start with `<time>` and has any amount of alphanumeric characters, colons (:) or dashes followed by a `</time>` tag. If you want to remove the spaces before the tag you can use the following instead:

find `[\t ]*<time>[0-9A-Z:-]*</time>` replace with blank.

If you want to remove the empty lines left over by doing this, you can use the TextFX plugin included with most versions of Notepad++:

TextFX -> TextFx Edit -> Delete Blank Lines

Or just switch to extended find and search for `\n\r`

Comment: Thanks that works for me!  But if the text between <time> and </time> includes a dot (.), the replace command does not succeed..

Comment: If you want to just purge all the `<time>` and `</time>` tags you can do what @Noel said and do a find and replace for `[\t ]*<time>.*</time>` that will get rid of all the time tags regardless of whats inside of them.

Answer (score 15):

Used `<time>.*?</time>` and it worked perfectly.

[image]