# Possible to search and replace a specific XML tag with children in Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have an XML script and almost every item in it contains a now redundant tag`<atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>`that I want to remove. Below is a sample of the code. How can I remove the tag and everything within it in Notepad++?

I tried `[\t ]*<atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>.*</atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>` as per [Remove specified tags in XML (notepad++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717938/remove-specified-tags-in-xml-notepad) but cannot seem to get it working.

Cheers.

```
        <atc:aircraft atc:idx="C63" atc:type="B747">
            <atc:flightpath>
                <atc:point atc:x='8.2338'   atc:y='48.9288'     />
            </atc:flightpath>
            <atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>
                <atc:flashItem>fl</atc:flashItem>
                <atc:colour>red</atc:colour>
            </atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>
        </atc:aircraft>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the checkbox in the Replace dialog for `. matches newline`.

See the image below. The regex you mention in your question works fine.

[image: checkbox missing]

For your **follow-up** question, what you are looking for, is look ahead regular expressions:

```
<atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>(.(?!<atc:acceptedStateFlashParams))*</atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>
```

You need to check that your `.` does not match the same tag that you wish to replace. Related read [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Comment: Thanks heaps for that, feel a little daft now. A follow up question, when I run that in my XML file with a whole bunch of them, for some reason it selects almost every `<atc:aircraft>` tag as well. 

The `.*` rule appears to be too lenient and is selecting EVERYTHING between the very first `<atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>
` and the last `</atc:acceptedStateFlashParams>` Any ideas?